# Cannot figure out AttributeError: has no attributes

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

Still very new to python and taking an online intro class. I cannot figure out this problem from my textbook and no answer key! This chapter is on classes and I think I almost have the answer right- I'm sure it's something silly I'm just totally missing! I keep getting AttributeError: module 'employee' has no attribute 'employee.

```
#The class represents the employee class
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, ID_number, department, job_title):
        self.__name = name
        self.__ID_number = ID_number
        self.__department = department
        self.__job_title = job_title
        
    def set_name(self,name):
        self.__name = name
        
    def set_ID_number(self, ID_number):
        self.__ID_number - ID_number
        
    def set_department(self, department):
        self.__department = department
        
    def set_job_title(self, job_title):
        self.__job_title = job_title
    
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    
    def get_ID_number(self):
        return self.__ID-number
    
    def get_department(self):
        return self.__department
    
    def get_job_title (self):
        return self.__department
        
import employee

def main():
    #create 3 instances of Employee  objects 
    SM_info = employee.employee ('Susan Meyers', '47899', 'Accounting', 'Vice President')
    MJ_info = employee.employee ('Mark Jones', '39119', 'IT', 'Programmer',)
    JR_info = employee.employee ('Joy Rogers', '81774', 'Manufacturing', 'Engineer')
    
    #print the employee objects
    print('Employee 1: ')
    display_employee(SM_info)
    
    print()
    
    print('Employee 2: ')
    display_employee(MJ_info)
    
    print()
    
    print('Employee 3: ')
    display_employee(JR_info)
    
def display_employee(employee):
    print('Name: ', employee.get_name())
    print('ID Number: ', employee.get_ID_number())
    print('Department: ', employee.get_department())
    print('Job Title: ', employee.get_job_title())
    
#call the main function
main()
```

Comment: is Employee class in sep python script name employee and rest of code in different file ?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your class, you're just importing something wrong..what are you importing when you run import employee?

Comment: I tried the suggestion in the Answers and that did not work. I then get this: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: as for what am I importing I'm importing the class which I created. In this case (for ease of viewing) I placed it above my main function.

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to create an employee, you're calling employee.employee. That's the attribute that doesn't exist.

You need to create an employee object like this:

SM_Info = Employee( 'Mark Jones', '39119', 'IT', 'Programmer',)

Answer (score 0):

hoping `Employee` class is in `employee.py` file. then  CODE is as

```
#The class represents the employee class # employee.py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, ID_number, department, job_title):
        self.__name = name
        self.__ID_number = ID_number
        self.__department = department
        self.__job_title = job_title
        
    def set_name(self,name):
        self.__name = name
        
    def set_ID_number(self, ID_number):
        self.__ID_number - ID_number
        
    def set_department(self, department):
        self.__department = department
        
    def set_job_title(self, job_title):
        self.__job_title = job_title
    
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    
    def get_ID_number(self):
        return self.__ID_number
    
    def get_department(self):
        return self.__department
    
    def get_job_title (self):
        return self.__department
        
    
    
# main.py 
        
from employee import Employee


def display_employee(employee):
    print('Name: ', employee.get_name())
    print('ID Number: ', employee.get_ID_number())
    print('Department: ', employee.get_department())
    print('Job Title: ', employee.get_job_title())
def main():
    #create 3 instances of Employee  objects 
    SM_info =  Employee('Susan Meyers', '47899', 'Accounting', 'Vice President')
    MJ_info =  Employee('Mark Jones', '39119', 'IT', 'Programmer',)
    JR_info =  Employee('Joy Rogers', '81774', 'Manufacturing', 'Engineer')
    
    #print the employee objects
    print('Employee 1: ')
    display_employee(SM_info)
    
    print()
    
    print('Employee 2: ')
    display_employee(MJ_info)
    
    print()
    
    print('Employee 3: ')
    display_employee(JR_info)
    

    
#call the main function
main()
```

Comment: It is and I finally at least got the first line to print with this code but after Employee 1: Name: Susan Meyers- I then get an AttributeError: "Employee" object has no attribute '_Employee__ID'

Comment: @dlk0219 i considered your code working fine, just a typo error in function  `def get_ID_number(self):`, fixed now